# Serialize nested object as flat attributes of current parent object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've model A and model B, model B is child of model A.

I've implemented a ModelSerializer for my model A object and I need to represent all attributes of related model B as attributes (properties) of model A.

How can I do that with Django Rest Framework?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add your serializer and models?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a child so :

```
class ModelB(ModelA):
```

You just need to specify the fields name explicitly in the serializer.

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('fieldFromB', 'fieldFromA', ....
        read_only_fields = ('fieldFromA', ...
```

If it is a m2m or FK relation create serializer for model A

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    SModelA= ModelASerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('fieldFromB', 'SModelA', ....
        read_only_fields = ('SModelA', ...
```

If it is a FK relation to model A, and u just want the PK from ModelA. Just add modelA into the fields and readonly fields

Comment: Hi, I forgot to specify that my ModelA and ModelB is in one2Many relationship.
So I need to have a ModelB serializer that contains all fields of the parent ModelA in the "flat" model.

Comment: One2Many is FK, foreign key.Write your ser for Model A